# How to Display the list of methods with signature in a java file using javaparser

Tags: java, javaparser

I need to display the list of methods along with signature for a java class using javaparser.

I know how to display the list of methods with out signature but not along with signature.
Can any one provide some examples to get methods along with signature.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with the *javaparser* but should be pretty straightforward. The HOWTO on their project site shows [how to create a `MethodVisitor`](https://code.google.com/p/javaparser/wiki/UsingThisParser#Changing_methods_from_a_class_with_a_visitor), there you get a [MethodDeclaration](https://code.google.com/p/javaparser/source/browse/trunk/JavaParser/src/japa/parser/ast/body/MethodDeclaration.java?r=63) which contains quite everything you need to construct a string with the signatures.